# What is the movie referenced in Black Panther with the "automatic shoes"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther-2018

In *Black Panther* before T'Challa goes on his mission to capture/kill Klaue he visits Shuri for some new tech. Here she gives him some "automatic shoes":

[image: GIF of T'Challa putting the shoes on]

She then says the following:

> **Shuri:** Try them on. Fully automated. Like the old American movie Baba used to watch.
>
> <sub>*Black Panther*</sub>

What is the movie she is referencing here?

Comment: https://www.thewrap.com/catch-back-future-ii-reference-black-panther/ https://comicbook.com/marvel/2018/02/16/black-panther-back-to-the-future-shuri-reference/

Comment: Man, now I feel old

Comment: @Kevin The movie will be 30 years old this year. And we're now 4 years past the movie's "future".

Comment: @Barmar Which is the same amount of time Marty McFly traveled back in the first movie.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

## *Back to the Future 2*

This is likely a reference to *Back to the Future 2*'s auto lacing shoes:

[image: Self-lacing shoes from Back to the Future 2]