# Identifying the writing inside T'Challa's shoes in this scene

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, translation, black-panther-2018

Following up on the question asked [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202757/what-is-the-movie-referenced-in-black-panther-with-the-automatic-shoes), what does the inscription inside the shoes mean?

[image]

Comment: Dunno... Puma? Nike? ;)

Comment: Left / right? :-D

Comment: Front toward enemy?

Comment: The left one seems to have a different inscription (ending with "a", according to the key from Neo Darwin's answer). Is there an image showing it in full?

Comment: @lfurini - See below

Answer (score 53, accepted):

User [UNITBlackArchive on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MovieDetails/comments/9z2ngo/hidden_pun_in_wakandan_in_black_panther_2018_when/)  identified the writing (in the [Wakandan alphabet](https://www.omniglot.com/conscripts/wakandan.htm) that was [devised by Hannah Beachler](https://www.indiewire.com/2018/02/black-panther-wakanda-written-language-ryan-coogler-afrofuturism-1201931252/)) as

> **heir t'chaka**

Presumably this is a pun on [Air Jordan](https://www.jordan.com/collection/)

[image]

Comment: So the answer to the question _"How many easter eggs can you put into a pair of shoes and still walk comfortably?"_ seems to be _"At least 2"_ (Air Jordan; Back to the Future).

Answer (score 27):

These are letters from [the Wakandan alphabet](https://www.omniglot.com/conscripts/wakandan.htm) that was [made for the film](https://www.indiewire.com/2018/02/black-panther-wakanda-written-language-ryan-coogler-afrofuturism-1201931252/):

[image]

In that language the shoes say **heir** (in lowercase).

Very cool touch imo. It perfectly describes King T'Challa. Really well done.

Comment: So is written Wakandan like Aurebesh, just a different script of English? Or does it just happen that "heir" is an English loanword? Or just Shuri's joke?

Comment: It's just a visual joke - I wouldn't read too much into it

Comment: @Adamant - It's just Aurabesh with vaguely 'African' looking letters